# Review and mentions about time discretization

Tags: time, resource-recommendations, discrete

I would like to get basic knowledge in this topic  of [time discretization](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=time+discretization), at least basics. Because of I'm new in this field I don't know what is better way to start. Could anybody suggest any reviews and books about such a topic, or at least where it was mentioned and discussed?

Comment: Are you familiar with spatial discretization? I only ask because the two are pretty much identical.

Comment: Just going to answer with eigenvalues of coordinate operator in QM, then found that you mean smt different. No I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: How are you planning on using the discretization, solving the Schoedinger equation or some similar partial differential equation?

Comment: Sorry for delay. So by means of finding of minimum eigenvalue of the coordinate operator. Then you can find a system where is eigenvalue is smallest among all quantum systems. And it will be a smallest distance.